# Get data from 2 different tables using JPA jax-rs REST service

Tags: java, rest, jpa

If I have one table named A_client, and another one named B_client. A_client has ID's and different status values, while B_client is holding personal data, such as name and adress.

How do I do this if I followed [this](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html) guide?

***Examples below to show you where I am***

I have a A_Client.java that looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A_client")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "AClient.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM AClient e"),
@NamedQuery(name = "AClient.findById", query = "SELECT e FROM AClient e WHERE e.Id = :Id"})
```

And I have a A_ClientFacadeREST that looks like this:

```
@Stateless
@Path("test")
public class AClientFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<AClient> {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "com.123_MavenProjectTest_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU")
private EntityManager em;

public AClientFacadeREST() {
    super(AClient.class);
}
@GET
@Path("id")
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public List<AClient> findById() {
    List<AClient> results = em.createNamedQuery("AClient.findById", AClient.class)
            .setParameter("Id", 1)
            .getResultList();
    return results;
}
```

***etc etc***

How do I manage to get data from B_Client aswell as A_Client using REST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set OneToOne relations between tables in your AClient entity

Comment: Do you have an example of how to do this? I've never done that before.

Comment: I posted Aclient in the js section here, just to paste it somewhere: http://jsfiddle.net/rzpg5yxg/

Comment: B_Client has the columns "ID, firstname, lastname, address" and A_Client has the column "ID" so far.

Comment: So in your AClient You have only ID? You can create entity BClient and add property BClient to AClient. And use anotation @OneToOne upon this property. Or merge this two tables into one if You can and add all properties you need.